# WP8 TextBlock text has color layers for certain characters

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I need to prevent the TextBlock from changing the color of special characters, it looks like the WP TextBlock recognizes some shapes as emojis and colors them but it seems there is no way to control it like in Windows 8 like this article says:

http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/appbuilder/archive/2013/11/11/xaml-text-improvements-in-windows-8-1.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox.iscolorfontenabled.aspx

There is no IsColorFontEnabled in WP, anyone knows how to override this behavior?

The problem is with the heart character ♥, and I would not want to use a list of heart shape paths

EDIT: I have used the ❤ character but has different spacing and coloring than the normal one, I think the only way is to use a list of paths with this shape :(

Thanks

Comment: I should read the question more thoroughly,  I posted an answer on how to make the text colored, not remove the colors.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the RichTextBox act like the TextBlock by setting the IsReadOnly property to true.  It looks similar to the TextBlock, while the TextBox doesn't.

I'm not sure if you can control the emoji problem with this idea, you'd have to test,  but it does allow you have full control over the color of text.

**XAML**

```
<StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Margin="12,0,12,0">
<!-- One Color-->
  <RichTextBox Foreground='White'>
    <Paragraph>Text with ☻</Paragraph>
  </RichTextBox>

  <!-- Multi color -->
  <RichTextBox IsReadOnly='True'>
    <Paragraph>
      <Run>Mixed Colors.</Run>
      <Run Foreground='Red'
           FontWeight='Bold'>☺</Run>
      <Run Foreground='Yellow'>☻</Run>
      <Run Foreground='LightGreen'>♫</Run>

    </Paragraph>
  </RichTextBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks but unfortunately didn't work with a richtextbox set as readonly, still shows the emoji colored

Comment: Good to know, too bad it doesn't solve your problem.